# presentationUploadExternalUrl in BigBlueButton Api

Tags: django, video-streaming, backend, presentation, bigbluebutton

I am using BigBlueButton Api to create meetings but they have added some new fields in the 2.6 version like presentationUploadExternalUrl the official documentations description describes the field as {*Pass a URL to a specific page in external application to select files for inserting documents into a live presentation. Only works if presentationUploadExternalDescription is also set.*}.

I am not sure what kind of url they are talking about is it a url to specific website if it is then what kind of websites??

I have tried adding the fields to the code and passed the google drive url but no change has been observed by me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.